# why the variables of Pagingnation class could not assigned?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to use pagingnation in my web page for that I used following code

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/admin/pages/';
        $config['total_rows'] = 5;//$this->pages_model->count_pages();
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['per_page'] = '2';
```

but the problem is that array variable $total_page and $per_page does not assigned value so can not display the paging links. I mean in create_links() I can not get the new value as assigned above.Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Load the pagination library

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
```

Intialize the pagination.

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Sharmaji, I have loaded the library in autoload file even I got the rows as set by the per page but pagingnation link does not display...

Comment: I have also face same kind of problem but when i put $this->pagination->initialize($config); ..It starts working...